# Why are basis transformations written in order reverse to that of conjugation?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, notation

Some time ago I posted a question here asking about the distinctions between the conjugation notation in group theory ($gxg^{-1}$ vs $g^{-1}xg$). I was under the impression that these are simply two different kinds of non-conflicting notation, but it was explained to me that the former defines a left action, while the latter defines a right one, so it's a matter of what kind of "orientation" one prefers. As I understand it, a significant portion of the mathematical community prefers writing functions before arguments and left actions, and, by that same logic, the former kind of conjugation. So then why are basis transformations usually written as $P^{-1}AP$? Isn't a basis transformation simply conjugation in $GL_n(k)$, why should it be written in the opposite order? I have seen authors write "left" conjugations and "right" basis transformations in the same books, why wouldn't this be inconsistent and conflicting notation?

Comment: What is the matrix $P$ in $P^{-1}AP$?

Comment: @amd since we're speaking of basis transformations, the invertible change of basis matrix, what else?

Comment: In which direction though? Once you’ve decided on that, if you think about the change of basis in terms of the “input” and “output” bases that $A$ expects, the expression is determined. In particular, if the original basis is the standard basis, then the columns of $P$ are typically taken to be the standard basis coordinates of the new basis vectors, and you end up with $P^{-1}AP$. It’s also consistent with the “bulk” eigenvector equation $AP=P\Lambda$—the diagonalization of $A$ is then $P^{-1}AP$.

Comment: @amd OK, now I think I see what you're getting at, your meaning was whether $P$ is the new basis written in the coordinates of the old or vice versa, am I correct? In that case, yes, it's in the direction you're talking about.

Comment: With the convention that you apply a linear transformation by left-multiplying by a matrix, $P^{-1}AP$ is forced.